# Why has this question been marked as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

See [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/111456/attach-to-a-gameobject-after-collision).

I find it very surprising that this question has been marked as duplicate and its user suspended (for one year!), which means that he cannot reply to any of his future answers. This question had already 2 up votes before it's been marked: it would for sure help other users as well as me. It also has one favorite. The user shows clearly what he needs and is explicitly showing the community what he has already tried by providing us with code. Secondly, I don't understand why this question has been marked in the first place. The supposed "duplicate" is not about the same issue encountered by the user. For the people who still didn't compare the two questions: on the linked question, the user is talking about **keeping a GameObject "attached" after collision even if it changes scale.** On the supposed duplicate, the user is asking for an alternative to his personal code so that he can **properly attach objects to each other**. It appears that the question has been falsely marked as duplicate. Another person is also expressing his disagreement: see [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/111456/attach-to-a-gameobject-after-collision?noredirect=1#comment194473_111456). Personally, I am also seeking an answer to this question because it would be extremely useful for a project I am working on. I believe that I am speaking for other members of this community as well. We would really appreciate this question to be "unmarked" as duplicate and its user "unsuspended", by our fellow moderators,  because it would benefit us all.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This question was marked as a duplicate because of it's similarity to the original and because both the original *and* the duplicate question were under the control of the same user through duplicate accounts. Therefor the appropriate course of action would have been to *not* create two questions but rather amend the original question.

If the community feels that there is a compelling enough difference in the two questions to keep them unique, they can flag it for reopening. Thus far no such flags have been raised, and only one comment to that effect has been posted.

The user posting the duplicate question was suspended for a year *not* because the question is a duplicate, but because the account is a duplicate and was being used to evade the suspension of the user's primary account.